# DefaultButton of 'panelName' must be the ID of a control of type IButtonControl

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, master-pages

I am developing a website on ASP.NET and using bootstrap for the design. I'm using modal fade class (like a popup) for user to login.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="login" role="dialog">
   <asp:Panel ID="AZloginPanel" runat="server">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
         <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="form-horizontal">
               <div class="modal-header">
                  <h4>Login</h4>
               </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
               <asp:Login ID="LoginUser" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" RenderOuterTable="false">
                  <LayoutTemplate>
                     <span class="failureNotification">
                        <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                     </span>
                     <asp:ValidationSummary ID="LoginUserValidationSummary" runat="server" CssClass="failureNotification"
                                        ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup" />
                     <div class="accountInfo">
                        <fieldset class="login">
                           <div class="form-group">
                              <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" CssClass="col-lg-2 control-label" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">Username:</asp:Label>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                   <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Username"></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName"
                                                    CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." ToolTip="User Name is required."
                                                    ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                           </div>
                           <div class="form-group">
                              <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" CssClass="col-lg-2 control-label" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password:</asp:Label>
                              <div class="col-lg-10">
                                 <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Password" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                              </div>
                              <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password"
                                                    CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="Password is required." ToolTip="Password is required."
                                                    ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                           </div>
                           <p>
                              <asp:CheckBox ID="RememberMe" runat="server" />
                              <asp:Label ID="RememberMeLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="RememberMe" CssClass="inline">Keep me logged in</asp:Label>
                           </p>
                        </fieldset>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                           <p class="pull-left">
                                <asp:HyperLink ID="RegisterHyperLink" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" NavigateUrl="~/Account/Register.aspx">Register</asp:HyperLink>if you don't have an account.
                           </p>
                              <asp:Button ID="CloseModal" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-info" CommandName="Close" Text="Close" />
                              <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" CommandName="Login" Text="Log In" ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup" />
                         </div>
                     </div>
                  </LayoutTemplate>
               </asp:Login>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</asp:Panel>
</div>
```

When I set `DefaultButton="LoginButton"` in `AZloginPanel` panel, I get the following error:

> The DefaultButton of 'AZloginPanel' must be the ID of a control of type IButtonControl.

I'm lost and I've tried everything but it seems I'm at dead end.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the [`asp:login`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178329(v=vs.100).aspx) control modifies the id's of it's children, so the [`asp:panel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel(v=vs.110).aspx) control does not know where to look to find the new `DefaultButton` id.

#### Here's a simplified version that reproduces the issue:

```html
<asp:Panel ID="AZloginPanel" runat="server" DefaultButton="LoginButton">
    <asp:Login ID="LoginUser" runat="server" >
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" />
            <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password" />
            <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" Text="Log In" />
        </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:Login>
</asp:Panel>
```

If you want to use a [DefaultButton for a LoginControl](http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/asp-net-setting-the-defaultbutton-for-a-login-control), you can do one of two things:

#### 1. Nest the panel inside of the login control:

```
<asp:Login ID="LoginUser" runat="server" >
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="LoginButton">
            <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" />
            <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password" />
            <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" Text="Log In" />
        </asp:Panel>
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:Login>
```

#### 2. Build the ID with the LoginControlID then `$` then Button ID:

```
<asp:Panel ID="AZloginPnl" runat="server" DefaultButton="LoginUser$LoginButton">
    <asp:Login ID="LoginUser" runat="server" >
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" />
            <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password" />
            <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" Text="Log In" />
        </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:Login>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: if you are using .Net 4.0 or higher, you can also use ClientIDMode and set it to static on the login button, so the clientID is equal to the ID